# ClickHandler get clicked element

Tags: gwt

When I'm adding a clickhandler to a button, im doing it like this:

```
button.addClickHandler(myHandler);

// myHandler
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // how to get the button here?
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the button object that has been clicked inside the clickhandler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write

```
Widget sender = (Widget) event.getSource();
```

Then, for each button, compare it to sender:

```
 private Button b = new Button("Button XXX");

if (sender == b) {
      // handle Button XXX being clicked
    }
```

Comment: ah getSource() that's it! Thank's a lot